# How to deploy and run python scripts inside nodejs application?

Tags: python, node.js, angular, file, mean-stack

I'm working with a MEAN stack application, that passes a file to python script, and this script doing some tasks and then it returns some results.
The question is and how to install the required python packages when I deploy it?

Thanks!

I've tried to run python code inside nodejs application, using python shell.

Comment: use child process

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Place python script along with requirements.txt(which has your python dependencies) in your nodejs project
  directory.
- During deployment , call pip install on the requirements.txt and it
  should install the packages for you.
- You can call python script from nodejs just like any shell command
  using inbuild child_process module or python-shell.